# Add install.ps1 on Class Library (.NET Standard) Project

Tags: powershell, nuget, visual-studio-2017

I have migrate my .NET Framework project to a .NET Standard project.

In the .NET Framework project i have a .nuspec file with additional file config and create the nuget package with "NuGet.exe pack"

```
  <files>
     <file src="Install.ps1" target="tools\Install.ps1" />
  </files
```

In the .NET Standard project i have not longer a nuspec file and switch to "msbuild -t:Pack" to create the nuget package. I have try to set the install.ps1 to (BuildAction = Content) but then i see a warning in the log "Issue: PowerShell file out side tools folder." And in the nupkg file the directory is "content\tools\Install.ps1" i need "tools\Install.ps1".

Comment: Any update for this issue? Could you get any useful information from answer? If not, please let me know the latest status of this issue.

Comment: Sorry no updates, my temporary solution is add the tools folder after creation with 7zip

Comment: @Leo-MSFT not sure if you get notified when a new answer is added, but I've added a solution that works for me (and appears to be the way to do it)

Comment: Do you have a new update for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get file into a different path in the package you can use the `<PackagePath>` element in the `<Content>` element like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="install.ps1">
        <PackagePath>tools\</PackagePath>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

(providing the `install.ps1` is in the root of your project, otherwise you'll have to adjust the `Include` attribute value)

For more information check out the docs about the `pack` MsBuild Target here:

https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/Adding-nuget-pack-as-a-msbuild-target

Answer (score 0):

> I have try to set the install.ps1 to (BuildAction = Content) but then i see a warning in the log "Issue: PowerShell file out side tools folder." And in the nupkg file the directory is "content\tools\Install.ps1" i need "tools\Install.ps1"

When you use `msbuild -t:Pack` to create the nuget package, msbuild/VS expects the files to be in content folder. But if you still want to the install.ps1 file in the `tools` directory, you can still use the `.nuspec` file and nuget.exe to pack the package.

**The detail steps to pack package:**

Create the .nuspec as below settings:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>TestInstall.ps1</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>Test</authors>
    <owners>Test</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Package description</description>
    <releaseNotes>Summary of changes made in this release of the package.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2017</copyright>
    <tags>Tag1 Tag2</tags>
  </metadata>

  <files>
    <file src="Install.ps1" target="tools" />
    <file src="bin\Debug\netstandard1.4\TestInstall.ps1.dll" target="lib\netstandard1.4" />
  </files>

</package>
```

Then use the command line: `nuget.exe pack xxx.nuspec` to pack the package, you will get the package with `Install.ps1` in the tools directory:

[image]